# MySQL: Error Code: 1411. Incorrect datetime value: '24102018915G' for function str_to_date 0.000 sec

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do some reverse engineering the following SQL is a working version. I am trying to create a staging database and the insert statement is failing.

Any idea what parameters I need to check to make it work in temp db??

```
INSERT INTO 
SECURITY_STAGING (INSERT_TYPE, ADDED_DTTM, SECURITY_CODE, SECURITY_NAME, SECURITY_GROUP, LAST_TRADED_PRICE, CHANGE_AMT, CHANGE_PER)  
VALUES ('GAINER',STR_TO_DATE('24102018915G','%d%m%Y%H%i'),'532524','PTC','A','78.00','3.10','4.14')
```

> Error Code: 1411. Incorrect datetime value: '24102018915G' for
>   function str_to_date  0.000 sec

Comment: how do you get the date time of '24102018915G' ? the error is clear about what causing the error.

Comment: Are you sure about the "g" letter of your string?

Comment: 24102018915G is picked up from the file name generated as per datestamp...seems the leading 0 for the time is missing.

Answer (score 1):

This produces a valid timestamp:

```
select STR_TO_DATE('241020180915','%d%m%Y%H%i')
```

This does not

```
select STR_TO_DATE('24102018915G','%d%m%Y%H%i')
```

You are missing a zero and have a G instead.